# Send event invitation from SharePoint calendar to attendee by email

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I've created calendar in SharePoint Online. Then I've added Attendees column with type User/Group.

After that I've created Workflow in SharePoint Designer to send email notifications for invited users.

I also can add SharePoint calendar as a second calendar in Outlook.

But I need to send **invitations** to users - special messages that user can accept or decline, and that event should be added to his own calendar in Outlook (not just in SharePoint calendar).

Is it possible to do?

Is it possible to send such invitations to external email addresses (users that has no access to SharePoint)?

Answer (score 2):

You must create custom code to do that. Check this links:

[Deliver meeting request from Sharepoint Calendar programmatically](https://nhutcmos.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/deliver-meeting-request-from-sharepoint-calendar-programmatically/)

[Construct and Send an ICS file as an attachment in the Email](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4cf18c/construct-and-send-an-ics-file-as-an-attachment-in-the-email/)

[Export (.ical) Individual Events from SharePoint Calendar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/20/export-ical-individual-events-from-sharepoint-calendar.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for answer!  Could I create this in App for SharePoint or it should be done as Sandboxed Solution?

Comment: Can I create Remote Event receiver in SharePoint App Solution to handle this?

Comment: I did not test in Remote Event receiver, but I think is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app that you can use to send invitations from a SharePoint Online calendar. Here are the details: http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/calendar-events-invites-add-in-now-available-for-sharepoint-online/