# How do I create an calendar event and send e-mail to all community site members?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I just want to create an event in calendar and an email is sent to every member, that's it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe people to the list by group or create a simple workflow that is fired off when the item is created.

You can more complex with the workflow if you like. If you want to  [Send a meeting invite for calender](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149416/send-event-invitation-from-sharepoint-calendar-to-attendee-by-email) see the link.

1. Create the new workflow. Add the send an email task. Look for the users you want emailed to and add them to it.
   [image]
2. Then set the workflow to only run on creation. 
   [image]
3. Publish it and you should be good to go.

You can also achieve this by using Gintas K solution with out having to do a workflow.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I wanted to create a workflow to trigger an e-mail Only to  sharepoint community members where event is created.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you very much, workflow works for me the way I expected. Now every time I create an event a email is sent to every community members only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Calendar List
2. Choose "Alert Me" & "Set alert on this list" from the ribbon

[image]

3. Setup your Alert

[image]

Comment: Hi Gintas, what I really want is to send an e-mail, every time a calendar event is created to every sharepoint community member rather than sending to everyone. Thank you by reply!

Comment: What do you mean by sharepoint community members? Everyone is pointing to every SP User on that site collection. Otherwise, create a SP Group and add all the people there, then specify the alert to send emails to that group :)